# Safecracker Registration Setup Problem

Tags: safecracker-registration

I was trying to install Safecracker Registration with the steps from the [site](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration).

I was able to do all the steps with no problems...except the last one.

> Configuring Safecracker
>
> Since you are using Safecracker as a registration form (at least in
>   this case), you must allow it to accept data from guests. Go to
>   Add-ons > Modules > Safecracker and find your Member channel, and
>   assign a member as a guest. It is recommended you create a new member
>   named Anonymous.

This is the page that the above paragraph refers to

[image]

I am just confused about

> Go to Add-ons > Modules > Safecracker and find your Member channel

since I don't see "Member Channel" anywhere.

I am doing it correctly?

P.S. I am using ExpressionEngine 2.5.5 and Safecracker Registration 1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly as far as I can tell. And you have a Members channel already, as it is appearing in the list. (The table with the header, "Members" is what I was referring to.) You could create a channel with any name and any field to store your member profiles, I just use the "Members" nomenclature by default.

Essentially what you are doing is telling Safecracker to allow members to post anonymously without being logged in. Since every entry must have an author, you must assign an "anonymous" author to each new profile until the member account is created. Once the member account is created, the profile is updated with the new member_id.

Safecracker Registration v1.2 applies a series of overrides that allows users to skip this step entirely. Since 1.2 is not yet released, I have not documented this as such.

Comment: I see. So that is what "Member Channel" is referring to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new channel or use existing one to store the content from the Safecracker form. You also need to register a new member to so the posts have an author (who may need access to post in that channe). In short, I would create a new channel called 'forms', and a new member called anonymous to post in the 'forms' channel.